# How to return geolocation response object to use as a parameter for another function

Tags: javascript, function, geolocation

I'm after a bit of help with functions and the HTML5 GeoLocation API.

I'd like to generate a url using the users current location (longitude and latitude).

I have managed to get the code working to find the current user's location
and assign the `position.coords` object to a variable called coords.

What I'd like to know is whether I can return the object in the locationSuccess function to then pass the object as a parameter for the generateURL function, and retrieve the latitude and longitude to console log the finished url.

I may be completely wrong, however some help would be great. TIA.

```js
// app.js

function getUserLocation() {

 function locationSuccess(position) {

  console.log("success");

  var coords = position.coords;

 }

 function locationError() {

  console.log("error")

 }


navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationSuccess, locationError);

}

function generateURL() {


}

function app() {

 getUserLocation();

}

window.onload = app();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning the object is a bit of trouble because the `getCurrentPosition` function is asynchronous.

You can just pass the `coords` object to the `generateURL` function as an argument and call it inside of `locationSuccess` function.

```js
function getUserLocation() {

  function locationSuccess(position) {
    console.log("success");
    var coords = position.coords;
    generateURL(coords);
  }

  function locationError() {
    console.log("error")
  }
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationSuccess, locationError);
}

function generateURL(coords) {
  var URL = 'http://example.com/?lat=' + coords.latitude + '&long=' + coords.longitude;
  console.log(URL);
}

function app() {
  getUserLocation();
}

window.onload = app();
```

---

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yuriy636/tx6peL1u/) // Snippet doesn't work because of iframe security issues

Answer (score 1):

Pass the variable `position` as a parameter to your `generateURL()` function. See the modifications and comments below.

```js
// app.js

function getUserLocation() {

 function locationSuccess(position) {
            console.log("success");

            var coords = position.coords;

            // Pass the object as a parameter to the generateURL() function.
            generateURL(position);
 }

 function locationError() {
     console.log("error")
 }

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationSuccess, locationError);

}

// Added: variable position as a parameter to the function
function generateURL(position) {
    console.log(position);

}

function app() {
    getUserLocation();
}

window.onload = app();
```